# urllib.request is not found by Python when trying to download images from URLs

Tags: python, urllib

I modified this code to download a list of URLs from a txt file to my machine

```
import urllib
import json

file = 'urls.txt'

with open(file, "r") as f:
  for x in f:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(x)
```

However, this is the error I get:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b64f4f339b91> in <module>()
      6 with open(file, "r") as f:
      7   for x in f:
----> 8     urllib.request.urlretrieve(x)

AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
```

My goal is to download all of these images in the directory `/content/flickr_27/distractors`

The file looks like this:

```
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1184/1013364004_bcf87ed140.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1108/1047095104_503998550b.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1359/1076885577_01ee16bf04.jpg
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/53/110432189_6da90fe89e.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1144/1153048029_d5e36d005a.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1239/1180945706_4465725d08.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1266/1197260875_fbb3051626.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1384/1198126442_4ff6606e45.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1319/1250291945_e9523d607f.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1207/1256618724_bbdd35b354.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1285/1258795778_98da5c307d.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1176/1277378574_82e61a7ef0.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1363/1277773985_50808f6ba0.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1402/1284498655_fd6fbc51f0.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1430/1296366058_e583c0f2b4.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1263/1327352537_0f162ecc6c.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1389/1332615141_df9e1f92f5.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1313/1346967623_b41d43cbc1.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1230/1346967901_929c77f46a.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1200/1346968027_f0785a97c5.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1002/1346968161_a538e89310.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1392/1346968559_6d160b4bbb.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1342/1347857496_b347d4dcb4.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1186/1347857626_4a2ed7c66c.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1057/1347857976_18bce65668.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1090/1347858036_4802201a89.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1015/1347858534_a84e17e7b3.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1326/1357097399_11941a51d3.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1053/1357097685_b6f5b92d7d.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1006/1386986521_8ab5851727.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1068/1389207575_2c99d86873.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1398/1389207881_df46f7c1d0.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1024/1390102658_880cb1bbe2.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1074/1402510645_d726f0b1ab.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1169/1402510653_e7426c5326.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1033/1403388874_30ecbcc81c.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1108/1403403936_0ef6a3e326.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1257/1403403944_2d8da3aee1.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1350/1403403960_a621774c19.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1334/1403411942_775699313e.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1378/1418996115_1ea174297c.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1066/1423871758_6c72adedaa.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1198/1423875908_f39732a383.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1223/1443010828_d381b18cfe.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1395/1444893174_a8dc5a835b.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1051/1459603275_b89ded82f2.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1258/1459603325_931c85083f.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1420/1459603363_6f32b18725.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1192/1459603459_5c9b171f4a.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1080/1459603491_dcfdbc9063.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1054/1459603553_e1bfd8e6c9.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1340/1460466372_9b2ee1d610.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1416/1460466398_8abb88f4e0.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1432/1460466474_f4905ef65c.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1044/1460466534_a76ede72ae.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1130/1466042184_1651bcd922.jpg
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1222/1489494207_6e3cd35e0c.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2314/1492799285_a8487547b2.jpg
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/237/1511766139_2e114546e6.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2142/1511989549_6b74ba05b0.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2312/1512537698_bfeb101755.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2095/1512646880_0ac5061b89.jpg
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/247/1512664926_db8508990b.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2295/1523995294_3c90e84166.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2384/1560418306_9e5a75889a.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2274/1570759317_a6422a1ab3.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2050/1587529783_96f86ebc30.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2033/1587531547_00bae9d416.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2024/1588415872_ea37052e47.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2420/1588422178_70522f86d9.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2178/1588423452_c33865e64f.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2366/1588424896_43f3e64893.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2149/1589477371_29c0fb19e7.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2130/1589895868_1beb4cab2e.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2402/1617466555_5905f29190.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2418/1618295528_0a68baf98d.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2036/1618685212_c4135ac9ef.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2211/1618728620_eec0aa419b.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2182/1626700592_69cf3caf3f.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2259/1629794767_f4a71780a3.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2058/1629797517_e59b786583.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2199/1629798005_ec59c3419d.jpg
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import request submodule like this:
`import urllib.request`